# How to add empty lines when displaying elements in an array

Tags: ruby

I have class `Actor` with some attributes.

```
class Actor
  attr_accessor :name, :age, :sex, :birth_date, :birthplace, :filmography, :death_date
  def alive?
    death_date.nil?
  end
end
```

When I iterate over an array `actors` of `Actors` and display the elements as follows:

```
display = actors.each do |i|
  puts puts i.inspect
end
```

I get empty lines between the items:

```
#<Actor:0x007f7c04da41c0 @name="Paul Newman", @age=83, @sex="M", @filmography=["Cool Hand Luke", "Butch Cassidy and the Sundance Kid"]>

#<Actor:0x007f7c04da40d0 @name="Catherine Keener", @age=52, @sex="F", @filmography=["Being John Malkovich", "Capote"], @death_date="Jan 01 2011">

#<Actor:0x007f7c04ba3c40 @name="Kathy Pornstar", @age=24, @sex="F", @filmography=["Pono", "Capote"]>
```

With the following code, the output does not have empty lines in between the items:

```
living = actors.select{ |i| "\n"; i.death_date.nil?}
puts "#{living}"
```

Output:

```
[#<Actor:0x007f7c04da41c0 @name="Paul Newman", @age=83, @sex="M", @filmography=["Cool Hand Luke", "Butch Cassidy and the Sundance Kid"]>, #<Actor:0x007f7c04ba3c40 @name="Kathy Pornstar", @age=24, @sex="F", @filmography=["Pono", "Capote"]>]
```

How do I make it such that the output has an empty line in between the items? Any formatting/re-formatting will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that by "space", you mean an empty line.

The reason `display` has empty lines in between is because you have two `puts`, used in a wrong way. It would be simplified to:

```
display = actors.each do |i|
  puts i.inspect, nil
end
```

and for `living`, you can do:

```
living.each do |e|
  puts e.inspect, nil
end
```

Comment: `living = actors.select{ |i| i.death_date.nil?}.each { |e| puts e.inspect, nil }`

Would this be incorrect style/syntax? The chaining of 2 blocks on a single line?

Comment: It is correct, but does not improve readability, and I see no point of doing it.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you want to print each actor in `living` on a separate line, you could do the following:

```
living.each do |actor|
  puts actor
end
```

Does that answer your question?

Comment: I'd appreciate it if whoever downvoted my answer could leave a comment explaining why, so I know what to be more careful of in the future.  Thanks!